# Adding calculated variable to a dataset using a loop

Tags: r, loops, variables

I have checked if others have asked this question but most answers talk about using vectors which i hope to tackle after understanding loops.

```
varlist <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")

for (i in varlist){
    Zscore<-(df$i - mean(df$i[df$time == 0], na.rm = T) ) /  sd(df$i[df$time == 0], na.rm = TRUE) 
    df[,paste0(i,"_Standard")] <- Zscore
}
```

I'm pretty sure my error is in line 4. When i run the Zscore code on individual variables I get the correct variable with correct scores. How do i assign the scores generated in the third line to the generated variable in line 4?

Once I can do this I will learn some vectorized alternatives.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Change the `df$i` to `df[[i]]`

Comment: Thank you! I'm not being told Error in `[.data.frame(df, , i) : undefined columns selected.`  when i assign the columns using `varlist <- c(colnames(df)[c(1,3,4,5)])` it indeed show that the variables are unnamed which doesn't make sense because I can see them and refer to them when coding the variables individually